# I want to load the page content (in a DIV) dynamically using a hashbang URL (blah.com/#!/thingtoload), I have jQuery and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website with Bootstrap and jQuery (latest from the jQuery CDN) and I want to load the content of the page within a DIV (that is, only a section of the page is loaded, the Bootstrap navbar at the top stays the same as well as other things like scripts, CSS etc.) when a link is clicked.

## Example:

My site URL is http://nintri.x10.mx/, and the front page is the same URL. On the page I would have a div with an id, for the purposes of this example, of *#pageContent*.
`<a href="#!/profile.php?user=jsa005">jsa005&apos;s Profile</a>`
should, when clicked, load /profile.php?user=jsa005 in *#pageContent*.
That's really all there is to it. ;)

Comment: Search questions on SO about History.js, github like navigation, single page application, angularJS spa.

Comment: Why are you using `#!` with `?`? Those are inherently two different ideas. You can use them together but it would probably be `profile.php?user=jsa005/#!something here` Not the other way around.

Comment: @user974407 Basically I want to load whatever's after the #!, for example nintri.x10.mx/#!/somepagetoload.php would load nintri.x10.mx/somepagetoload.php in the div, and nintri.x10.mx/#!/profile.php?user=jsa005 would load nintri.x10.mx/profile.php?user=jsa005 in the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `window.location.hash` (if you were to do this manually. There are of course scripts for this). 
You could just load the script from the hash directly like you wanted. Then load the html that the script returns directly to your content's html.

```
$(function(){
  $("#clickme").on("click", function(e){
      var hash = window.location.hash.replace('!','');
      //or $.ajax or $.get or other.
      $.get(hash,function(data){
         $("#content").html(data);
      })
  });
}
```